# -PARTOF condition in UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I need to add -PARTOF condition for the annotations which startswith some prefix.

**Example:**

**Sample Annotation:**

```
AAA_sample
BBB_text
AAA_test
```

From the above example i need to add -PARTOF(AAA_(.+?)) like that.Is it possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

The `PARTOF` condition accepts only a type expression as an argument, thus you would need to create an annotation of a specific type for each AAA at the beginning of an annotation before. The `STARTSWITH` condition would probably be suited better here.

```
DECALRE Prefix;
(CAP.ct=="AAA" SPECIAL.ct=="_"){->Prefix};
Annotation{-STARTSWITH(Prefix)};
```

Specific to your sample annotations, I would use the `REGEXP` condition:

```
Annotation{-REGEXP("^AAA_.+")};
```

However, **you should not match directly on Annotation**, but rather on a more specific type like Token depending on your use case.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*